# Word page indicator stops working when addin is activated

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in

I have a Word 2010 and 2013 addin that works pretty fine right now but I noticed that once it is activate in Word, the page indicator, the one that is in Word's status bar at the bottom, usually indicating your current location i.e. "Page 4 of 7", simply stops working. I can still use Word without any other issue, but when I change pages, the indicator doesn't change, it displays what it was displaying when the addin was activated.

I'm just wondering if anyone ever encountered this problem before or if anyone as an idea about what could causes this?

Thanks!

Alex

Comment: Showing or Hiding the Navigation Pane using the ribbon OR by clickint the page numbers in the status bar seems to bring back things to normal. This issue seems to happen when I modify the document's content from my C# code. I get the IntPtr Handle of the Word application in order to show a progress bar in a modal window and when all my process is completed the modal window is closed, word gains back the focus but the page numbers stop updating when I change pages... I wonder if I could refresh this from my code...

Comment: It seems to be caused by the modal window itself. The simple fact of displaying a modal window from my add-in code freezes the page number indicator in the status bar. until I show or hide (if its visible already) the navigation pane...

I commented the lines that show and close the modal window and it solves the problem. I just don't get it. I really need to be able to display my progress bar and lock the UI while it is displayed. The modal window works just fine for that but for some reason it freezes the status bar.